# Closed-form upper-bounds for Wasserstein distance between finite measures

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, optimal-transportation

Let $x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n\in \mathbb{R}$ and such that $x_i\neq x_j$ and $y_i\neq y_j$ if $i\neq j$.  Let $a,b$ be elements of the probability n-simplex.  Define the measures $\mu\triangleq \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \delta_{x_i}$ and $\nu\triangleq \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \delta_{y_i}$.  Are there known, (not too lax) upper-bounds for
$$
W_p(\mu,\nu) \leq M\left(x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n,a,b\right)
$$
for some continuous function $M$; known in closed-form such that
$$
M(x_1,\dots,x_n,x_1,\dots,x_n,a,b)=0.
$$

Where $W_p$ is the Wasserstein-1 distance, for some $1\leq p<\infty$?

Comment: The Wasserstein distance is an infimum, so should be bounded by any feasible matching. Any feasible assignment based on a greedy approach will make do. Control by weighted total variation (see the book by Villani, 2008) could also help.

Comment: The worst you can do, is the 'democratic' coupling $\pi := \sum_{i,j} a_ib_i\delta_{x_i}\otimes \delta_{y_j}$, which gives you the upper bound  $$M= ( \sum_{i,j} a_ib_j |x_i-y_j|^p )^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$

Comment: I refined my question since there are too many "lax" upper-bounds available...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$F(x):=\mu((-\infty,x])=\sum_i a_i\,1(x_i\le x)
=\sum_{j=1}^n s_j\,1(x_{n:j}\le x<x_{n:j+1}),$$
where $x_{n:1}<\cdots<x_{n:n}$ are the values $x_1,\dots,x_n$ put in the increasing order (with $x_{n:n+1}:=\infty$),
$$s_j:=\sum_{i=1}^j a_{n:i},$$
and  $a_{n:1},\dots,a_{n:n}$ are the values $a_1,\dots,a_n$ put in the increasing order of the $x_k$'s, so that, if $x_{n:i}=x_k$ for some $k$, then $a_{n:i}=a_k$.
So, $F$ is the cdf of the probability measure $\mu$. Similarly considered is the function $G$ defined as the cdf of the probability measure $\nu$.

Consider then the generalized inverse/quantile function $F^{-1}\colon(0,1)\to\mathbb R$ defined by
$$F^{-1}(u):=\inf\{x\in\mathbb R\colon F(x)\ge u) \\
=\max\{x\in\mathbb R\colon F(x)\ge u) \\
=\sum_{j=1}^n x_{n:j}\,1(s_{j-1}<u\le s_j)$$
for $u\in(0,1)$, with the similarly defined and considered $G^{-1}$. Let $U$ be a random variable (r.v.) uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. Then the distributions of the r.v.'s $X:=F^{-1}(U)$ and $Y:=G^{-1}(U)$ will be $\mu$ and $\nu$, respectively. Finally, let
$$M(x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n,a,b):=M(\mu,\nu) \\ 
:=(E|X-Y|^p)^{1/p}
=\Big(\int_0^1|F^{-1}(u)-G^{-1}(u)|^p\,du\Big)^{1/p}.$$
Then
$$W_p(\mu,\nu)\le M(x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n,a,b)$$
and
$$M(x_1,\dots,x_n,x_1,\dots,x_n,a,a)=0,$$
as desired.

---

*Remark:* The upper bound $M(\mu,\nu)$ given above is actually the exact value of the Wasserstein distance for $p\ge1$, according to the last sentence of [Theorem 2.1](http://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Emthorpe/OTNotes) -- thank you alesia for this reference.

Comment: Why did you only state an inequality? Isn't that the exact value of the Wasserstein distance (you missed an exponent p btw)?

Comment: @alesia : The upper bound $M(\mu,\nu)$ given in the answer will in general be the exact value of the Wasserstein distance only for $p=1$ -- see e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.04945.pdf

Comment: The first equation p 10 in http://www.math.cmu.edu/~mthorpe/OTNotes says it's true for all p

Comment: @alesia : Yes, you are right, and, when one thinks about this a bit, it is almost obvious! -- The two mass distributions should be matched in the increasing order.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  Thank you Iosif and alesia for the very helpful insights!

Comment: One may add that this method also work for continuous distributions.

Comment: Does an analogue of this method also hold for data in high-dimensions (ie $d\neq 1$)

Comment: Also, for your solution we donr requires the $x_i$ and $y_j$ to be distinct right?

Comment: @Elbebe : I don't think that there is a similar method for higher dimensions. On the other hand, only minor edits are needed to remove the distinctness condition.

Comment: For higher dimensions one could use that $W_p(\mu,\nu)\geq \sup\{\int f\,d(\mu-\nu)\mid Lip(f)\leq 1\}$ so any Lipschitz-1 function gives a lower bound. One may construct some $f$ in some greedy fashion (this does not lead to an "explicit" formula, but a straightforward algorithm for a lower bound).

Comment: (The result is in "On a Formula for the L2 Wasserstein Metric between Measures on Euclidean and Hilbert  Spaces" by Gelbrich)

Comment: @Dirk : Thank you for your comments. However, (i) this way you get an upper bound, not a lower one -- which is what was actually needed ; (ii) how to assure that the bound is tight?

Comment: @Dirk I think that lower bound (is only also an "upper-bound") iff the involved measures are Gaussian (if I remember the paper correctly)

Comment: Oops - I have no idea why I thought that a lower bound was wanted…